How to insert the time in a text field inverted
I'm trying to create a regular expression mask to insert the time starting with seconds, minutes and finally the hour.
For example, showing 12:34:56 after typing - 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
I tried creating a regular expression, but I'm not very experienced. If you can help me I would be very grateful
This is my regex that didn't work:
function timeinvert(v) {
  v = v.replace(/\D/g, "");
  v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d)/, "$2$1")
  v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d)(\d)/, "$3:$2$1")
  v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)/, "$4$3:$2$1")
  v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)/, "$5:$4$3:$2$1")
  v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)\d+?$/, "$6$5:$4$3:$2$1")
  // v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1:$2")
  // v = v.replace(/(\d{2})\d+?$/, "$1")
  return v;
}


Why would someone enter the time in reverse?

if you want to create a regular expression mask to insert the time starting with the hours, minutes and finally seconds you can use the following function.
function timeForward(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, "");
    if (v.length <= 2) {
        return v;
    } else if (v.length <= 4) {
        v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, "$1:$2");
    } else {
        v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, "$1:$2:$3");
    }
    return v;
}


What I understand is something like this;


var str = "6,5,4,3,2,1";

var reg = /(\d),(\d),(\d),(\d),(\d),(\d)/;

console.log(str.replace(reg, "$6$5:$4$3:$2$1"));




Start by inserting : after every other character. Then reverse it.


function timeinvert(str) {
  time_arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i % 2 == 0) {
      time_arr.push(':');
    }
    time_arr.push(str[i]);
  }
  time_arr = time_arr.reverse();
  return time_arr.join('');
}

console.log(timeinvert('654321'));
console.log(timeinvert('54321'));
console.log(timeinvert('4321'));
console.log(timeinvert('321'));
console.log(timeinvert('21'));
console.log(timeinvert('1'));




Yet another way of doing it is by reversing the number on entry. Here's a quick take on that. There's easier ways of doing this, but this is what I came up with off the cuff.
In any case, there are definitely some edge cases to figure out here: what do you want to happen while the user is entering the data? For instance, after they've entered 6,5,4; should they see 4:56 or 45:6 or 45:60 or 40:56?
You'll need to adjust the code to handle those and other cases as necessary.


document.querySelectorAll('.reverso-time').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
      if (e.target.value.length) {
      e.target.value = (e.key + e.target.value.replaceAll(/\D/g, '').split('').reduceRight(
        (agg, cur, idx) => (`${(idx % 2 === 0 ? `${cur}:${agg}` : `${cur}${agg}`)}`), 
        ''
      )).slice(0, 8).replace(/^:|:$/, '');
      e.preventDefault();
      }
      break;
    case ':':
      e.preventDefault();
      break;
    case 'Backspace':
    case 'Delete':
      e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/^:|:$/, '').replace(/(:\d{1})$/, '$10');
      break;
    default:
      console.log(e.key);
      break;
  }
}));
<label>Enter time in reverse:&nbsp;<input type="text" class="reverso-time"></label>



